# Eclipse Leshan server and client with secure keys fails with RequestTimeoutException

Tags: java, eclipse, iot

The `LeshanStandalone.java` and `LeshanClientExample.java` that come with the Leshan source code are not setup with secure client connections.

So I borrowed some code from `SecurityTest.java` and `SecureIntegrationTestHelper.java` to setup the server and client.

My modified LeshanStandalone code:

```
public class LeshanStandalone {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LeshanStandalone.class);

    private Server server;
    private LeshanServer lwServer;

    public void start() throws NonUniqueSecurityInfoException {


        // Build LWM2M server
        LeshanServerBuilder builder = new LeshanServerBuilder();
        builder.setLocalAddress(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 5683));
        builder.setLocalAddressSecure(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 5684));

        // Get public and private server key
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        PublicKey publicKey = null;

        try {
            // Get point values
            byte[] publicX = DatatypeConverter
                    .parseHexBinary("fcc28728c123b155be410fc1c0651da374fc6ebe7f96606e90d927d188894a73");
            byte[] publicY = DatatypeConverter
                    .parseHexBinary("d2ffaa73957d76984633fc1cc54d0b763ca0559a9dff9706e9f4557dacc3f52a");
            byte[] privateS = DatatypeConverter
                    .parseHexBinary("1dae121ba406802ef07c193c1ee4df91115aabd79c1ed7f4c0ef7ef6a5449400");

            // Get Elliptic Curve Parameter spec for secp256r1
            AlgorithmParameters algoParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
            algoParameters.init(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
            ECParameterSpec parameterSpec = algoParameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);

            // Create key specs
            KeySpec publicKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(new ECPoint(new BigInteger(publicX), new BigInteger(publicY)),
                    parameterSpec);
            KeySpec privateKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(privateS), parameterSpec);

            // Get keys
            publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            builder.setSecurityRegistry(new SecurityRegistryImpl(privateKey, publicKey));
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidParameterSpecException e) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to load RPK.", e);
        }


        lwServer = builder.build();

        lwServer.getSecurityRegistry().add(SecurityInfo.newPreSharedKeyInfo("lwm2mClient", "testclient", DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("73656372657450534b")));
        lwServer.start();

        // Now prepare and start jetty
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = System.getProperty("PORT");
        }
        if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }
        server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(webPort));
        WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
        root.setContextPath("/");
        root.setResourceBase(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("webapp").toExternalForm());
        root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(root);

        // Create Servlet
        EventServlet eventServlet = new EventServlet(lwServer);
        ServletHolder eventServletHolder = new ServletHolder(eventServlet);
        root.addServlet(eventServletHolder, "/event/*");

        ServletHolder clientServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ClientServlet(lwServer));
        root.addServlet(clientServletHolder, "/api/clients/*");

        ServletHolder securityServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new SecurityServlet(lwServer.getSecurityRegistry()));
        root.addServlet(securityServletHolder, "/api/security/*");

        ServletHolder objectSpecServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ObjectSpecServlet());
        root.addServlet(objectSpecServletHolder, "/api/objectspecs/*");

        // Start jetty
        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("jetty error", e);
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            lwServer.destroy();
            server.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NonUniqueSecurityInfoException {
        new LeshanStandalone().start();
    }
}
```

my modified LeshanClientExample.java:

```
public class LeshanClientExample {
    private String registrationID;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 4 && args.length != 2) {
            System.out
                    .println("Usage:\njava -jar target/leshan-client-example-*-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar [ClientIP] [ClientPort] ServerIP ServerPort");
        } else {
            if (args.length == 4)
                new LeshanClientExample(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), args[2], Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
            else
                new LeshanClientExample("0", 0, args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        }
    }

    public LeshanClientExample(final String localHostName, final int localPort, final String serverHostName,
                               final int serverPort) throws Exception {

        // Initialize object list
        ObjectsInitializer initializer = new ObjectsInitializer();
        initializer.setClassForObject(3, Device.class);
        List<ObjectEnabler> enablers = initializer.createMandatory();

        // Create client
        final InetSocketAddress clientAddress = new InetSocketAddress(localHostName, localPort);
        final InetSocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(serverHostName, serverPort);

        CoapServer serverLocal = new CoapServer();

        // Get point values
        byte[] publicX = DatatypeConverter
                .parseHexBinary("fcc28728c123b155be410fc1c0651da374fc6ebe7f96606e90d927d188894a73");
        byte[] publicY = DatatypeConverter
                .parseHexBinary("d2ffaa73957d76984633fc1cc54d0b763ca0559a9dff9706e9f4557dacc3f52a");
        byte[] privateS = DatatypeConverter
                .parseHexBinary("1dae121ba406802ef07c193c1ee4df91115aabd79c1ed7f4c0ef7ef6a5449400");

        // Get Elliptic Curve Parameter spec for secp256r1
        AlgorithmParameters algoParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
        algoParameters.init(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
        ECParameterSpec parameterSpec = algoParameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);

        // Create key specs
        KeySpec publicKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(new ECPoint(new BigInteger(publicX), new BigInteger(publicY)),
                parameterSpec);
        KeySpec privateKeySpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(new BigInteger(privateS), parameterSpec);


        // Get keys
        PublicKey serverPublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
        PrivateKey serverPrivateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        DTLSConnector dtlsConnector = new DTLSConnector(serverAddress);
        dtlsConnector.getConfig().setPreferredCipherSuite(CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8);
        dtlsConnector.getConfig().setPskStore(new StaticPskStore("testclient", DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("73656372657450534b")));
        dtlsConnector.getConfig().setPrivateKey(serverPrivateKey, serverPublicKey);
        dtlsConnector.getConfig().setRequireClientAuth(true);

        serverLocal.addEndpoint(new CoAPEndpoint(dtlsConnector, NetworkConfig.getStandard()));

        final LeshanClient client = new LeshanClient(clientAddress, serverAddress, serverLocal, new ArrayList<LwM2mObjectEnabler>(
                enablers));


        // Start the client
        client.start();

        // Register to the server provided

        RegisterResponse response = client.send(new RegisterRequest("lwm2mClient"));

        // Report registration response.
        System.out.println("Device Registration (Success? " + response.getCode() + ")");
        if (response.getCode() == ResponseCode.CREATED) {
            System.out.println("\tDevice: Registered Client Location '" + response.getRegistrationID() + "'");
            registrationID = response.getRegistrationID();
        } else {
            // TODO Should we have a error message on response ?
            // System.err.println("\tDevice Registration Error: " + response.getErrorMessage());
            System.err.println("\tDevice Registration Error: " + response.getCode());
            System.err
                    .println("If you're having issues connecting to the LWM2M endpoint, try using the DTLS port instead");
        }

        // Deregister on shutdown and stop client.
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (registrationID != null) {
                    System.out.println("\tDevice: Deregistering Client '" + registrationID + "'");
                    client.send(new DeregisterRequest(registrationID));
                    client.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Device extends BaseInstanceEnabler {

        public Device() {
            // notify new date each 5 second
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fireResourceChange(13);
                }
            }, 5000, 5000);
        }

        @Override
        public ValueResponse read(int resourceid) {
            System.out.println("Read on resource " + resourceid);
            switch (resourceid) {
                case 0:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getManufacturer())));
                case 1:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getModelNumber())));
                case 2:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getSerialNumber())));
                case 3:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getFirmwareVersion())));
                case 9:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newIntegerValue(getBatteryLevel())));
                case 10:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newIntegerValue(getMemoryFree())));
                case 13:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newDateValue(getCurrentTime())));
                case 14:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getUtcOffset())));
                case 15:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getTimezone())));
                case 16:
                    return new ValueResponse(ResponseCode.CONTENT, new LwM2mResource(resourceid,
                            Value.newStringValue(getSupportedBinding())));
                default:
                    return super.read(resourceid);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public LwM2mResponse execute(int resourceid, byte[] params) {
            System.out.println("Execute on resource " + resourceid + " params " + params);
            return new LwM2mResponse(ResponseCode.CHANGED);
        }

        @Override
        public LwM2mResponse write(int resourceid, LwM2mResource value) {
            System.out.println("Write on resource " + resourceid + " value " + value);
            switch (resourceid) {
                case 13:
                    return new LwM2mResponse(ResponseCode.NOT_FOUND);
                case 14:
                    setUtcOffset((String) value.getValue().value);
                    fireResourceChange(resourceid);
                    return new LwM2mResponse(ResponseCode.CHANGED);
                case 15:
                    setTimezone((String) value.getValue().value);
                    fireResourceChange(resourceid);
                    return new LwM2mResponse(ResponseCode.CHANGED);
                default:
                    return super.write(resourceid, value);
            }
        }

        private String getManufacturer() {
            return "Leshan Example Device";
        }

        private String getModelNumber() {
            return "Model 500";
        }

        private String getSerialNumber() {
            return "LT-500-000-0001";
        }

        private String getFirmwareVersion() {
            return "1.0.0";
        }

        private int getBatteryLevel() {
            final Random rand = new Random();
            return rand.nextInt(100);
        }

        private int getMemoryFree() {
            final Random rand = new Random();
            return rand.nextInt(50) + 114;
        }

        private Date getCurrentTime() {
            return new Date();
        }

        private String utcOffset = new SimpleDateFormat("X").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        ;

        private String getUtcOffset() {
            return utcOffset;
        }

        private void setUtcOffset(String t) {
            utcOffset = t;
        }

        private String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();

        private String getTimezone() {
            return timeZone;
        }

        private void setTimezone(String t) {
            timeZone = t;
        }

        private String getSupportedBinding() {
            return "U";
        }
    }
}
```

The server starts ok, but the client starts on 5684 with a `RequestTimeoutException`, and the server prints:

```
May 19, 2015 2:47:04 PM org.eclipse.californium.scandium.dtls.Record fromByteArray
WARNING: Received illegal record content type: 68
May 19, 2015 2:47:07 PM org.eclipse.californium.scandium.dtls.Record fromByteArray
WARNING: Received illegal record content type: 68
```

What have i done wrong or missing?